# Store latitude in 3.5 bytes

Tags: java, c, floating-point

I know that title sounds little bit weird but it's extremely important to compact our message into 16 bytes. However, whole data is 17. The only possible solution that I can think of is to try to save one byte putting coordinates into 7 bytes instead of 8.

Requirement for coordinates is to store value with 5 decimal places as the very minimum, e.g., 0.00001.

Say we have 3.5 bytes (28 bits). One bit will be used for sign, another 4 for scale, 2 for exponent and 21 bits for decimal points which are 2097152 of unique values which is enough to store 6 decimal places even.

My question is how can I convert 4 byte float to 3.5 byte float in C/Java? Can you refer me to existing solutions for "fine-tuning" floats like this where I can define all the components of float number? Thanks.

Comment: Looks like in worst case scenario only 4 decimal places are guaranteed.

Comment: just truncate the mantissa off of a normal 4 byte float

Comment: Save yourself a bit for the sign.  Measure latitude from 0 at N Pole to 180 at S pole, longitude from 0 at Greenwich meridian eastwards to 360 at Greenwich meridian.  Then consider using your remaining bits as an integral number of, say, arc-seconds (or centi-arc-seconds or whatever) rather than fiddling around with a non-standard f-p representation.

Comment: Just a guess, but "shift"?  And, probably, "mask"?

Comment: You may want to look at the `BitSet` class, too -- it may help

Comment: Well, it's pointless (actually "stupid" is closer) to use a float for this.  You want equal precision across the range of values.

Comment: Divide 180 by (2**28) -- that's your scale factor.  Fixed point.

Comment: Would be interesting to know what are the remaining 9 bytes: any redundant info with lat/long (eg N/S) would help to reach your 7 bytes storage. We could have suggestions regarding these 9 bytes...

Comment: @HotLicks just a warning, you need to handle sign extension(int32_t(var)<<4>>4). otherwise that works perfectly for a small fixed point representation

Comment: @SteveCox - It's always a positive number, 0-180, and there are no "left-over" bits into which to extend the sign.

Comment: @HotLicks oh you're using HPM's sign reduction. thats fine

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My first choice in this case wouldn't be a strange 3.5 byte "float" but to pack it into an integer. Assuming your latitude range is -90 to 90 and longitude from -180 to 180 it would look something like this (Cish code, untested):

```
 float latitude = 45.12345
 float longitude = 110.12345

 unsigned int packedLatitude  = (latitude + 90) * 100000     //25 bits
 unsigned int packedLongitude = (longitude + 180) * 100000   //26 bits

 float unpackedLatitude  = packedLatitude / 100000.0f - 90.0f
 float unpackedLongitude = packedLongitude / 100000.0f - 180.0f
```

This gives you your coordinate in 6.4 bytes. All that is left is to pack these 6.4 bytes into your 16-18 byte structure which I assume you already know how to do (it depends on what you're packing it into and where).

Note there are a few gotchas with this method you need to be aware of. The lower limits (-90 and -180) are hard limits and if exceeded your unpacked coordinates won't be correct. Your upper limits have a little give: latitude can go to 245, longitude to 491 but you probably should make sure they are normalized to -90-90/-180-180. If it matters you should also be aware of how you are rounding or truncating extra digits below 0.00001 (I believe this method truncates them).

Comment: I would add `long long result7bytes = packedLatitude * 36000000 + packedLongitude;` and, to retrieve data `packedLatitude = result7bytes / 36000000 ; packedLongitude = result7bytes % 36000000;`. If my math is correct, you could go even to 6 decimals (360,000,000 * 180,000,000 < 2^56).

Comment: @ring0 right 55.8 bits, but float won't have this accuracy anyway (except near greenwich and equator). A 24 bits significand only fulfills an accuracy of roughly 1e-5 degree in longitude. In other words, you can't get much than 24 bits+24 bits (except near zero)

Answer (score 5):

Float makes no sense here.  You almost certainly want the same precision (in terms of degrees of arc) at the North Pole, the Equator, and the South Pole.  So all zeros should represent 0 degrees at the North Pole and 28 bits of 1s should represent the South Pole.

So zero degrees represents zero in your number, and 180 degrees represents (2 ** 28) - 1, or 268435455.  Multiply your latitude (in "double" degrees from the North Pole) times 268435455 / 180 or 1491308.0833333333, cast to an integer, and take the low-order 28 bits.  (The high 6 bits should be zero.)

To convert back, isolate the 28 bits in an int, cast to a double, and divide by the above factor.

Longitude can be handled similarly, only the range is 360 degrees rather than 180.

Comment: so 28 bits is just to preserve extra precision near greenwich and equator, because otherwise 24 bits are enough if floats where used in the first place...

Comment: @aka.nice - If you use IEEE floating point you lose 8 bits to the exponent before you start.  So one could achieve precision equivalent to the truncated 28-bit IEEE float with a 20-bit fixed-point number.  I only used 28 bits above because that was the specified number of bits available.  (And I specified starting/ending with `double`, since the 28-bit number carries more precision than as standard `float`.)

Answer (score 3):

i do not understand the need for scale since exponent and scale are almost the same.

you may look for the specification of IEEE Floats as used by C implementations. so you can store your value in a float cast it into a uint32 and extract the sign and exponent and mantissa information from it and pack it in your smaller format.

```
float    val     = 234.323f;
uint32_t valB    = ((uint32_t*)(&val));
uint32_t signBit = valB >> 31;
uint32_t exp     = (valB >> 23) & 0xff;
uint32_t mant    = valB & 0x7FF;
```

now you have the single components. store these within your data with the required precisision and do back conversion vice versa.

One caveat: the exp is stored with an offset of 128, so you have to transfer it back to signed and store it with another offset that fits your requirements

http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754#Zahlenformate_und_andere_Festlegungen_des_IEEE-754-Standards  (look at the colored image)

edit:
to fit your needs you can strip to lowest bits from mantissa without any concerns (but you may want to round up if bit 1 is set) and you have to strip 2 bits from exponent.

```
uint32_t smallMant = mant>>2;
int32_t  realExp   = ((int32_t)exp) - 128;
uint32_t smallExp  = realExp + 32;

uint32 reducedData28 = (signBit << 27) | (smallExp << 21) | smallMant;
```

If the exponent of your desired range is not symmetrical you may choose another offset than the half of the possible range.

Comment: In Java you can use `Float.floatToIntBits()` to get an int whose bits you can twiddle.